# Sprites distorted within viewport

Tags: c#, viewport, monogame

My understanding of Viewport is that it crops an area of the screen at the position and dimensions specified.
I have a large 2D tile map which requires cropping to display only inside a smaller square area of the screen, so as to view only that area of the larger map.
However, after implementing a viewport with the following code, any sprite drawn while the viewport is in effect is highly distorted, as if the entire original screen dimensions are scaling down to fit the dimensions of the viewport.

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime_) {
                SpriteBatch spriteBatch = screenManager.spriteBatch;
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,BlendState.AlphaBlend,SamplerState.PointClamp,DepthStencilState.Default,RasterizerState.CullNone);
                //draw panel
                spriteBatch.Draw(minimapPanelGfx,new Vector2(panelX,panelY),Color.White);
                //set up and activate viewport
                Viewport mapView = new Viewport(panelX+88,panelY+55,260,260);
                Viewport origView = TQGame.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
                TQGame.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport = mapView;
                //draw minimap (simplified as example)
                spriteBatch.Draw(minimapGfx,new Vector2(panelX+100,panelY+100),Color.White);
                //restore original fullscreen viewport
                TQGame.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport = origView;
                //
                spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Although the desired map display should remained unscaled, the viewported map display is condensed into the left upper side of the viewport. All I wish to achieve is to draw only the area of the full-scale map that falls within the viewport borders. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

--

**SOLVED**: It occurred to me to place the viewport code outside the SpriteBatch code and now it's working as intended. :)

Comment: I think this 'might' be related with how you're using `SamplerState.PointClamp`, and if the sprites are at the same sizes as original. But I can't picture the scene without a picture.

Comment: @Steven I tried changing the SamplerState to its other modes as well as changing the various other settings for the SpriteBatch, but any success I had in preventing the sprite distortion also ignored the effect of the viewport.

Comment: @Steven Eureka! It occurred to me to place the viewport code outside the SpriteBatch code and now it's working great! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved, you can post your solution as an answer. That way other visitors will know the question is answerred. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurred to me to place the viewport code outside the SpriteBatch code and now it's working as intended. :)